# Change property value on nested objects Angular 4+

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I'm trying to create a dynamic nested object but i can't change the value of the properties that I'm creating

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Test 1';
    expectedResult = {
      "0": { test: "Whoever" },
      "1": { test: "Whoever" },
      "2": { test: "Whoever" },
      "3": { test: "Whoever" },
      "4": { test: "Whoever" },
      "5": { test: "Whoever" },
      "6": { test: "Whoever" },
      "7": { test: "Whoever" },
    };
    obj = <any>{};
    test() {
      for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        // how do i write this line 
        this.obj[i].test = "Whoever" //<-------------------------
      }
    }
  }
```

**Html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" (click)="test()">
Test me</button>
<pre>
  {{obj|json}}
</pre>
<pre>
  {{expectedResult|json}}
</pre>
```

Adding stackblitz for reference.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mavvtogotest

**EDIT**

Thanks everyone helping, (I'm sorry) maybe I didn't explain it well. The solution must work over several nested objects example:

```
 expectedResult = {
"0": {
  "0": {
    "0": { "test": "Whoever" },
    "1": { "test": "Whoever" },
    "2": { "test": "Whoever" }
  },
  "1": {
    "0": { "test": "changeMe","notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "1": { "test": "changeMe","notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "2": { "test": "changeMe","notToBeChanged":"oldValue" }
  },
  "2": {
    "0": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "1": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "2": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" }
  }
},
"1": {
  "0": {
    "0": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "1": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "2": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" }
  },
  "1": {
    "0": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "1": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "2": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" }
  },
  "2": {
    "0": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "1": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "2": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" }
  }
},
"2": {
  "0": {
    "0": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "1": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "2": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" }
  },
  "1": {
    "0": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "1": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "2": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" }
  },
  "2": {
    "0": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "1": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" },
    "2": { "test": "changeMe" ,"notToBeChanged":"oldValue" }
  }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the console you see this error there

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'test' of undefined

Which means when you are doing `this.obj[i].test`, `this.obj[i]` is undefined. to solve the issue use below code. also I made your `obj` typed to get benefit of type checking.

```
  obj : {[key:string]: {test: string}} = {};
  test() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
      // how do i write this line
      this.obj[i] = { test : "Whoever" }
    }
  }
```

### Update based on comments

In case you want to update existing items on your obj you can use below code, so it won't overwrite if there was other properties there as well

solution 1

```
  this.obj[i] = Object.assign({} ,this.obj[i], { test : "Whoever" });
```

solution 2

```
  if (this.obj[i] == null) { this.obj[i] = {};}
  this.obj[i].test = "Whoever";
```

Comment: this is great but i think i't would be better to create an interface like so:  

    export interface testObj {
     [keys: string]: { test: string }
    }

Comment: The problem is that I can't access the property value on nested objects, if you use this.obj[i]={test:'Whoever'} you are setting the hole object again. that solution becomes useless if you want to change only one property on several nested objects like obj:{"0":{"1":{"2":{"changeMe":"value", "butNotMe":"value"}}}}

Comment: @MiguelAlejandroVillagrnVall see my updated response

Comment: Still won't solve the multi-nested object, please read my Edit or if i'm wrong about your approach please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }
    obj = <any>{};
    ngOnInit() {
        this.test();
    }

    test() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            this.obj[i] = {test: 'Whoever'};
        }
        console.log(this.obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain what the problem is, not just the solution. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that I can't access the property value on nested objects,  if you use this.obj[i]={test:'Whoever'} you are setting the hole object again. that solution becomes useless if you want to change only one property on several nested objects like obj:{"0":{"1":{"2":{"changeMe":"value", "butNotMe":"value"}}}}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you couldn't set the property of an undefined. (see console log for see this). Never hard code the length that you want to iterate, it's not good practice. Also, don't use **var** anymore. We are in the ES6+ era where we use **let** and **const**

```
  test() {
    let obj :  Result;
    obj = {test:'ahuevo'};
    for ( let i = 0; i <= Object.keys(this.expectedResult).length-1; i++) {
      this.objs[i] = obj;
    }
  }
```

I created an interace too

```
export interface Result {
  test: string;
}
```

Take a look to this stackbliz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mavvtogotest-enl8f3

Comment: The problem is that I can't access the property value on nested objects, if you use this.obj[i]={test:'Whoever'} you are setting the hole object again. That solution becomes useless if you want to change only one property on several nested objects like obj:{"0":{"1":{"2":{"changeMe":"value", "butNotMe":"value"}}}}